# How can I tell which dolls are unique and need to be collected?

Tags: stacking

In Stacking, you're encouraged to collect all of the unique dolls in each level.

**How can I tell which ones are unique without stacking into every doll in the level? Is there a way to differentiate between collected and non-collected unique dolls?**

Comment: Wait, did I really just ask a question about collecting dolls on the internet? I'm not sure what to think about this.

Comment: At least you're not collecting certain kinds of pictures to give a guy to make you doll outfits.

Comment: @GraceNote I do hope you are talking about a game...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is typically at least one doll per level that has an ability that causes its top half to unscrew and levitate.  This ability will highlight all the unique dolls in a small radius with a blue aura when used.  In the train station, this doll is a blonde woman in a pink hat who carries binoculars, and her ability is called "Eagle Eye."

Also, each unique doll shimmers slightly purple, although this can be hard to see if you're standing behind them and could stack, as the "stack" highlight tends to override the faint purple highlight of the "unique" doll.

You can tell if you've already gotten a unique doll by checking the "Collection" screen on the pause menu.  If you're far enough into the game, you can also visit the secret hideout where your hobo friend keeps track of all the unique dolls you've stacked with.  Alternatively, you can just stack with the doll and see if you get a notification :)

Although you'll have to stack with most of the unique dolls in order to solve every puzzle every possible way, there are several that will be unavailable until you've completely finished the puzzles they are part of.  For instance, the dolls guarding each puzzle area on the cruise ship level will not turn their backs to you until you've completed the puzzle they are in charge of in all possible ways.

Also, note that there is one unusually large doll in the train station which you can't stack with until you've completed the "cruise ship" level and returned to the station.

Achievement Hunters also did a series on all of the unique dolls, the first of which is here:

(These guys tend to use some NSFW language, be warned...)

Comment: This is an extremely thorough and awesome answer. I had seen the Eagle Eye ability, but I didn't realize that's what it did. Thanks very much, this helps quite a bit!